# Steam Alternative to Dota 2 Installation

Tags: games, steam

I connect to internet via proxy which has blocked Steam ports and I want to install DOTA 2 to play offline.
Is there an alternative installation procedure to Steam by which I can install DOTA 2 on my Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score -1):

If the proxy has the ports blocked there is little you can do about it if you don't own it.
Also, **DOTA2** has no offline capabilities that I'm aware of, since most of the calculations are done serverside, and yes, even the bot matches are done 'online', so to speak.
You should probably take it to the *[dev forums](http://dev.dota2.com/)*, where there are people who can help you with this **DOTA2** related issue.

Comment: You can play Dota2 even without internet connection.